# python-problem-report python-apport apport break apt-get

Tags: apt

I can no longer install or upgrade packages with `apt-get` since the packages `python-problem-report`, `python-apport` and `apport` seem to cause some problems. Any `apt-get` command I have tried results in the following error message:

```
Preparing to replace python-problem-report 2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1 (using .../python-problem-report_2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1_all.deb) ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 64
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 64
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python-problem-report_2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 36, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to replace python-apport 2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1 (using .../python-apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1_all.deb) ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 64
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 64
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python-apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 36, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to replace apport 2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1 (using .../apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1_all.deb) ...
apport stop/waiting
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 64
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 64
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
apport start/running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 36, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-problem-report_2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This happens even if I try to install packages that have nothing to do with the 3 trouble-making packages. I also selected "Lock at Current Version" in `muon` for these 3 packages, but the same error still occurs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem. I had manually installed a newer version of `python` (version 3.2 but the version installed through packages is 2.7) and I just redirected `/usr/bin/python` to `python3.2`. Apparently in 3.2 some syntax used in `/usr/bin/pyclean` is not valid anymore. Restoring the original link of `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python2` solved the problem. Now the scripts could be run without any issues.

I hope this helps somebody...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. A cleaner solution is to use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python

There are 3 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3     30        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2.6   20        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python2.7   10        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/python3     30        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Then pick the one you want to use. To resolve this problem I switched back to 2.7 and then reset to 3 after clearing things up with apt.

Comment: To continue Erik's answer above, his command didn't work on my system. I used this URL to get to where he already is (hope this is helpful to someone else): [https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux)